# Ignoring file extensions on Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to create a simple rewrite rule that ignores any extension that is added to a request. For example, both `foo.bar` and `foo.don` would point to the file `foo`. If this is not possible, can I add aliases to files? A third option is to upload an extra version of the file with the extension for every extension that the file should be available, but I don't think this is a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirection rules in S3 only work on prefixes, not extensions or with regexes.   You can, however, create empty objects at the alternative paths, with `x-amz-website-redirect-location` in the metadata, which will redirect the request elsewhere with a `301 Moved Permanently` response.  This, at least, prevents you from incurring redundant storage charges.

Like all redirects, this feature only works on requests sent to the S3 web site endpoint, not the REST endpoint.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html

The alternative would be to use a reverse proxy server in front of the bucket, to rewrite requests before they hit S3.